# Downloading new WorldClim version 2.1 bioclimatic variables for specific region of world using R

Tags: raster, r

I want to download the new [(19) WorldClim Bioclimatic](https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html) variables (version 2.1) for a specific region of the world, but it looks like you can only download the entire world, which is around 10 GB!

Around 8hrs to download with my internet connection.

I know there is a way to download tiles in R using the `raster` library. Here is the code:

```
library(raster)
getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-60, lat= -37, download = TRUE, path = "")

    *trying URL 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/tiles/cur/bio_44.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 5663180 bytes (5.4 MB)
    downloaded 5.4 MB*
```

As you can see, this works for worldclim version 1.4 ([data are obsolete](https://www.worldclim.org/data/v1.4/worldclim14.html)). Anyway to do the same but with worldclim 2.1?

Comment: I can't see any mention of the 30degree tiles on the web site for version 2, unlike for version 1.4. Have you tried worldclim's contact address? https://www.worldclim.org/about.html

Comment: The standard 30 second Bioclimatic variables for WorldClim version 2 can be downloaded at this link https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html

Comment: Yes what I am talking about are the 30degree x 30 degree tiles (https://www.worldclim.org/data/v1.4/formats.html) which save you having to download the whole globe if you only need part. I can't see an equivalent for v2.x and have you tried contacting WorldClim about that?

Comment: I just wrote an email to info@worldclim.org and sfick@ucdavis.edu.

Answer (score 1):

This is the new version code with pacakge geodata

The following code will download 12 maps (each for one month) see WorldClim website for more info, Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQZNpyEgVss) for a tutorial of map making.

```r
library(geodata)
MAPPP<-worldclim_global('tavg', res=10 ,path='YOUR WORKING PATH HERE')
# if you dont want to download the whole world, use worldclim_tile() or worldclim_country()
southA<-crop(MAPPP,extent(-82,-34,-60,15))
# To focus on south America
plot(southA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I found it in another website.

"for quick and dirty solution you can replace the url that the `getData()` function reads for bioclim data. You can find the source code of the function here [https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/getData.R#L277>](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/getData.R#L277%3E) . Note that there's if/else flow for different resolutions of climate data). From there you can make a custom function."

Also personally I used the code below here to download entire world data for V2 or V2.1 (basically any updated version). Replace the url and the file name in `destfile` and in unzip to the version and resolution you are using.

```
# Download 2.5 res worldclim V 2.1
P_url<- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/base/wc2.1_2.5m_bio.zip"
download.file(P_url, destfile="wc2.1_2.5m_bio.zip")
unzip("wc2.1_2.5m_bio.zip")
```